# C++ does not name a type in use of classes

Tags: c++, class, extern

I want to modify object "t1" of the class "abc" in "update" function which is defined in different file(temp2.cpp) than where "t1" is defined(temp1.cpp). I tried to use extern but that resulted in error. Please suggest nice way of doing this.

temp1.ccp

```
#include<iostream>
#include "test2.cpp"

using namespace std;
class abc{
  public:
    int x;
    char y;
    void printxy(){
      cout<<x<<y<<endl;
    } 
};

abc t1;
int main(){
  update();
return 0;
}
```

test2.cpp

```
extern abc t1;
void update(){
    t1.x=5;
    t1.y='A';
    t1.printxy();
};
```

In file included from test.cpp:2:0: test2.cpp:1:8: error: `abc' does not name a type
 extern abc t1;
        ^

test2.cpp: In function `void update()':

test2.cpp:3:2: error: `t1' was not declared in this scope   t1.x=5;

Comment: test2.cpp has no concept/idea of the class and its internals - it would if you supplied a header file defining it.

Comment: **Never** include `.cpp` files. That's the wrong approach!!

Comment: what are you trying to solve/achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You include `test2.cpp` before the declaration of class `abc`: the included file just gets expanded at the location where the `#include` occurs. You might want to use your code with the compiler's `-E` option to see how the file looks after preprocessing (in which case you probably also want to omit the `#include <iostream>` as it will produce lots of output).

In general, it isn't a good idea to include `.cpp` files. Did you mean the declarations to be a header file (e.g., `test2.h`) and include that at the type of `test2.cpp`? In that case the order of the declaration would be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it. Thanks for your comments :)

class.h

```
class abc{
  public:
    int x;
    char y;
    void printxy(){
      std::cout<< x << y <<std::endl;
    }; 
};
```

func.h

```
extern abc t1;
void update(){
  t1.x=5;
  t1.y='A';
  t1.printxy();
};
```

main file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "class.h"
#include "func.h"

abc t1;

int main(){
  update();

return 0;
}
```

Output

> > 5A